# "Diferencias en instanciar objetos sin el operador New o con el operador New"

Tags: java, java-ee

Hay algunas clases como la clase String, la cual existen diferentes formas de instanciar objetos como por ejemplo :

```
String Nombre = "Juan";
```

ó

```
String Nombre = new String("Juan");
```

En todo caso cual seria la diferencia de hacerlo de una de las 2 maneras, y que clases aparte de la String esto es permitido

Answer (score 3):

#### **¿Cuál es la diferencia entre String y new String()?**

La diferencia principal es que usando

```
String Nombre = new String("Juan");
```

estas creando un nuevo objeto.

Pero si en cambio "creas" un objeto de esta forma,

```
String Nombre = "Juan";
```

puedes obtener un objeto ya existente del [**String Pool**](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-string-pool-un-concepto-importante/), que es una especie de "Caché" del objeto `String`.

> [**Java String Pool**](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-string-pool-un-concepto-importante/) Cada vez que nosotros necesitamos crear una
> nueva cadena Java revisa si ya existe en el pool, en tal caso nos
> devuelve una referencia a ella, si no existe creará un nuevo objeto el cual almacenará en el pool para su futuro uso.

Answer (score 1):

Esto solo puedes hacerlo con la clase `String` (como bien indicas) y con los wrappers de los tipos primitivos (`Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, `Character`,...).

En el caso de la clase `String` ocurre algo especial y es que la VM es quien se encarga de crear internamente las instancias correspondientes a partir de los literales cuando sea necesario, ya que hay casos en los que, como te explican en otra respuesta, esta detecta que existe un objeto con el mismo valor en el STRING POOL y retorna esta misma referencia.

Cuando se trata de una clase wrapper se lleva a cabo un proceso denominado Auto-boxing que no es otra cosa que en tiempo de compilación reemplazar el literal por una expresión java que permita crear un obejto a partir de este. Por ejemplo:

```
// Para este código
Integer i = 7;

// El compilador reemplaza el literal 7 con esta expresión
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(7);
```

En este caso el método `valueOf()` es quien utiliza el operador `new` internamente.

Las clases wrapper mantienen una `cache` que funciona de modo similar al STRING POOL pero al contrario de este solo almacena un número finito de objetos (generalmente en el rango -128, 127, para los objetos cuyos valores estén fuera de este rango siempre se crea una nueva instancia). Esta es la razón por la que el compilador no convierte el literal directamente en una expresión con el operador `new` como esta:

```
Integer i = new Integer(7);
```