# Duda al instanciar, o dar un valor directamente a un String

Tags: java

cual es la diferencia entre hacer:

```
String miString = new String();
```

Y hacer:

```
String miStringDos = "hola";
```

En la segunda no estamos instanciando un objeto pero igual le puedo dar un valor. Osea  no se si me equivoco, (puesto que soy nuevo). ¿Pero en la segunda estoy creando  una variable de tipo Objeto no ? Si es asi no se que diferencia hay,ayuda por favor.

Comment: Esto se respondiò previamente aquì: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290508/diferencias-en-instanciar-objetos-sin-el-operador-new-o-con-el-operador-new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En ambos casos estás creando un *objeto*. En Java las cadenas en realidad son **objetos**.

La diferencia radica que en el primer caso estás creando un objeto de tipo `String`, en la cual, internamente tendrá una cadena vacía. En cambio, en el segundo caso, creas un objeto con inicialización (la cadena no está vacía).

**Comprobación:**

```java
String str1 = "Hello";
String str2 = new String();
System.out.println(str1.length());
System.out.println(str2.length());
```

Resultado por pantalla:

```java
5
0
```

Sin embargo, [no se suele crear un objeto cuya cadena sea vacía](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String()) (aunque eso dependerá del problema, en algunos casos puede ser útil como en este [ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/339105/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-cambiar-un-car%C3%A1cter-por-otro-en-una-cadena-sin-utilizar-replace/339128#339128)), debido a que, la clase `String` es inmutable. Así que cuando vuelvas a crear otro objeto, se perderá la **dirección base del objeto anterior**.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
String str2 = new String();
str2 = "Pepito";
```

Sin embargo, si tenemos este ejemplo:

```java
String str1 = "Hello";
String str2 = new String("Hello");
```

Si habrá una diferencia significativa. En el primer caso la máquina virtual de Java verificará si la cadena literal `Hello` se encuentra en el [String Pool](https://www.journaldev.com/797/what-is-java-string-pool) (es un bloque de memoria donde se aloja las cadenas constantes), si es verdadero, no necesita volver a crear otra vez un objeto.

En cambio, en el segundo caso, la máquina virtual de Java no hará ninguna optimización porque creaste el objeto con el operador `new`, por lo tanto, no hará ninguna verificación en el `String Pool`.

El objetivo del `String Pool` es para no consumir recursos de forma innecesaria. Imagínate tener muchas cadenas llamadas `Hello`, no hay la necesidad de crear un objeto por cada cadena, ya que es la misma. Con un objeto bastaría.

**Nota:** En el `String Pool` solo se almacena cadenas literales (es decir, cadenas que se conozcan en tiempo de compilación).

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

**String** es un **Objeto** solo que se puede atajar sin poner el *new*, y lo puedes declarar como un tipo de java *'normal'*. Pero la diferencia es que en el primero estas declarando el **String** pero no le das valor, y en el segundo le estas asignado unos valores, pero a efectos de declarar una cadena de texto, te da igual utilizar una u otra.

Answer (score 1):

Aca lo que estas realizando es definir ese string con esa cadena de caracteres, no olvides que un string es un vector de caracteres :)

```
String miStringDos = "hola";
```